# Gradient artifacts

Tags: html, css, css3, pdf, градиент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вывести страницу в печать в браузере через Ctrl + P, то видно как в PDF появляются артефакты в виде тонких полос, в данном случае видна красная вертикальная. Кто нибудь знает как исправить этот артефакт?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1158420/178988