# Нужно задать тексту градиент

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, градиент

```css
.one{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1f4ea2 0%, #36a9e1 60%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="one">Example text</div>
```

Нужны разные методы для создания линейного градиента для текста, так как с данным методом некорректно отображается в режиме печати (ctrl + P в браузере) появляются артефакты - тонкие линии

Comment: На css больше нету вариантов

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1158353/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy Чем проявляется связаность? Здесь есть только связность. Да, в вопросах, есть похожие слова, но здесь они применяются в другом контексте.

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович, именно из-за разного контекста была отклонена тревога на удаление одного из вопросов как дубликата другого. Тем не менее, весьма возможно, что решение одного вопроса может быть применимо и для другого.

Comment: Уважаемый @Qwertiy, согласен с вашей точкой зрения, но в данном вопросе  просто хочу узнать про различные способы создания текстового градиента )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет возможности проверить на принтере, поэтому только, как вариант - реализация с помощью параметра наложения:

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  background: white;
  color: #808080;
}

.one::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1f4ea2 0%, #36a9e1 60%);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Example text</div>
```